# Get taxonomy description based on variable

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to display a taxonomy description based on which taxonomy the page is set to display (set with a variable)

As it is, I'm only seeing the first description, regardless of which category variable is set.

Here's how I've set it up:

I've built a custom post type called 'product' and set up a taxonomy called'product_type'.

```
    //Register product post type
    add_action('init', 'product_register');
    function product_register() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => ('Products'),
            'singular_name' => ('Product'),
            'add_new' => ('Add New'),
            'add_new_item' => ('Add New Product'),
            'edit_item' => ('Edit Product'),
            'new_item' => ('New Product'),
            'view_item' => ('View Product'),
            'search_items' => ('Search'),
            'not_found' => ('Nothing found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => ('Nothing found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
            );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tag',
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'revisions', 'editor','thumbnail'),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => "product"), // Permalinks format
            );
        register_taxonomy('product_type', array('product'), array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Product Type',
            'singular_label' => 'Type',
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true)
        );
        register_post_type( 'product' , $args );
    }
```

In the wordpress back end, I've loaded this with a few terms and have also added in descriptions.

[image: Admin category list with values]
archive-products.php works like a landing page, but will accept information from a variable called $type to filter the content.

```
    if (isset($_GET['type']) || !empty($_GET['type']) ) {
        $filtered = true;
        $type = $_GET['type'];
    }
```

With that information, I can set up a WP_Query for items that contain that taxonomy term.

```
    if ($filtered == true) {
        $type = explode(' ', $_GET['type']);
        $taxonomy = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $type
                )
            );
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'DEC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'offset' => '0',
        'tax_query' => $taxonomy
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($the_query->have_posts()):
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_type' );
    if($terms) {
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->description; //always shows first term description, but should display description based on $type
    }
    }
    while($the_query->have_posts()):$the_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
    endwhile;
    else: //nothing to show here
    endif;} else {
    // non-filtered page design
    }
```

The query works great but, as I mentioned earlier, it's only pulling the first taxonomy description.

This is the part that is meant to handle that:

```
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_type' );
    if($terms) {
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->description;
    }
    }
```

I had guessed that it needed to be inside the query to land on the correct description, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I have also tried this:

```
    $term = get_term_by( $post->ID, $type, 'product_type' );
    echo $term->description;
```

but that doesn't return anything.

I'm out of ideas. I haven't found anything via google or by searching this site.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a specialized wordpress stackexchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ . I guess you will have a higher chance for an answer there, as your question is very specific

Comment: I've found things on that site in the past and it never occurred to me that it was part of the stack exchange family. Thanks for the info, I'll post it over there and see if anyone has a solution.

Comment: [Pieter Goosen over at wordpress.stackexchange had an answer for me.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195165/get-taxonomy-description-based-on-variable/195172#195172)